# Sort a list according a specific portion in the list Python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list in the format:

```
Apple, Orange[123 431]43351
Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423
Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342
....
....
```

I want to sort the list according to the number after the bracket ']'.
The output should be:

```
Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423 
Apple, Orange[123 431]43351 
Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342
```

I am trying to sort the list by using this:

```
LIST.sort(key = lambda x: x.split()[1])
for item in LIST:
    print(item)
```

I can find the last number by this: 
But I am not able to sort it

```
for item in LIST:
    bracket_index = item.find("]")
    end_of_line = item[bracket_index + 1:]
    if bracket_index != -1:
        print(end_of_line)
```

Comment: `LIST.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split(']')[1]))`?

Comment: Just a note, ALL_CAPS is usually used for constants, that is variables that do not change. If you are sorting the list, it probably doesn't fall under that category.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the format of your list?  Is it a list of tuples or a list of strings?  This works:

```
a = ['Apple, Orange[123 431]43351',
'Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423',
'Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342']

a.sort(key = lambda el: el.split(']')[1])
print(a)

Output:
 ['Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342',
 'Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423',
 'Apple, Orange[123 431]43351']
```

If it is a list of pairs of strings instead, then you should use `key = lambda el: el[1].split(']')[1]` like so:

```
a = [('Apple', 'Orange[123 431]43351'),
('Banana', 'Cherry[141 421]23423'),
('Coconut',' Mango[23 12312]232342')]

a.sort(key = lambda el: el[1].split(']')[1])
print(a)

Output:
[('Coconut', ' Mango[23 12312]232342'),
 ('Banana', 'Cherry[141 421]23423'),
 ('Apple', 'Orange[123 431]43351')]
```

Comment: my list is in the format:
list = ['Apple, Orange[123 431]43351',
'Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423',
'Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342']

I want the output to be:
Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423
Apple, Orange[123 431]43351
Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342

Comment: @VaibhavBorkar Well that is exactly the format I have addressed in my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with @Psidom's suggestion:

```
LIST.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(']')[1]))
```

Notice the use of `int()` to ensure the sort is done *numerically* rather than by string comparisons (which are done lazily; i.e., `'4321'` is considered "larger" than `'20000000'` due to `'4' > '2'`).

---

Full example:

```
LIST = [
    'Apple, Orange[123 431]43351',
    'Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423',
    'Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342'
]

LIST.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.split(']')[1]))
print(LIST)
```

---

A better method would be to parse your strings first. For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re

FruitTuple = namedtuple('FruitTuple', ['fruit', 'color', 'num1', 'num2', 'num3'])

unparsed_list = [
    'Apple, Orange[123 431]43351',
    'Banana, Cherry[141 421]23423',
    'Coconut, Mango[23 12312]232342'
]

split_list = [re.search('(\\w+), (\\w+)\\[(\\d+) (\\d+)\\](\\d+)', x).groups() for x in unparsed_list]
fruit_list = [FruitTuple(*x) for x in split_list]
fruit_list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.num2))

print(fruit_list)
```

Produces:

> [FruitTuple(fruit='Banana', color='Cherry', num1='141', num2='421', num3='23423'), FruitTuple(fruit='Apple', color='Orange', num1='123', num2='431', num3='43351'), FruitTuple(fruit='Coconut', color='Mango', num1='23', num2='12312', num3='232342')]

Comment: It isn't exactly true that string comparisons consider only the first few characters. That depends on how similar the strings are. When comparing `this` with `thin`, all characters would be compared.

Comment: I am getting a syntax error for  the statement(key = lambda x: )

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the `']'`

Comment: I am getting error 'None type object has no attribute group'

Comment: I posted a "Full example".

Comment: It doesnt seem to work in my program.  I think it is because I had got my list by sorting it from a file.